# Error when compiling GCC from Scratch: Makefile:555: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

Using arch linux latest version of GCC Source

Here is the Shell Output

```
[root@archserver build-gcc]# make all-gcc
Makefile:555: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Here is lines 554 - 559 in the Makefile

```
#### host and target specific makefile fragments come in here.
@target_makefile_frag@
@alphaieee_frag@
@ospace_frag@
@host_makefile_frag@
###
```

Any Solutions? Anyone Seen this Issue?

Comment: Please show us your `configure` and `make` invocations before you ran `make all-gcc`.